# How to decode URL-encoded (Percent Encoding) values in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I get a value back from a server which is already encoded (e.g. `some%20%5BURL%5D%20value`) and would need to decode it on the fly to send it back as a Header or in the Body (where it shouldn't be encoded).

Any way to do that in Paw?

Answer (score 1):

You can decode URL-encoded values with the *URL-Decode Dynamic Value*. Right-click on any text field, and choose Encoding > URL Encoding > Decode.

[image: How to decode URL-encoded (Percent Encoding) values in Paw]